# Sequelize UTC DateTime where clause query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am using Sequelize for MYSql Database, I have datetime property in mysql which stores datetime property in UTC, at the time of reading I have local time which needs to be compared with datetime column in where clause. How can I convert UTC column to local time to compare with local time?

Answer (score 0):

Convert UTC column to local time to compare with local time like this

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(your_datetime_column, '+00:00', '+05:30') <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Comment: I am using sequelize, dont want to use raw query in sequelize.